# Usar cp para crear fichero con el contenido de varios ficheros

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu

me gustaría saber si puedo crear un nuevo fichero con el contenido de **arch1.txt** y **arch2.txt** *(en la imagen se ven)* usando el comando cp.

[image: Creo dos archivos.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con el comando `cat`, tal como lo estás mostrando, peor no con el comando `cp`.

Ejemplo:

```
# cat archivo1.txt archivo2.txt archivo3.txt >> archivo4.txt
```

Y con esto tendrás el contenido de `archivo1.txt`, `archivo2.txt` y `archivo3.txt` juntos dentro de `archivo4.txt`